# Creating an error log if error occured while mapping SkyDrive as a network drive and copying files to it

Tags: batch-file

Hello to all community members,
I'm currently using a simple batch script to mount SkyDrive as a network drive, copy files to it, and at the end disconnect it. I use this as a basic form of off-site backup.

```
@echo off
echo Backing up to Skydrive
net use Z: \\https://d.docs.live.net/XXXX Password /user:Username
copy D:\Home\Data\file1.ext Z:\
copy D:\Home\Data\file2.ext Z:\Documents
net use Z: /delete
```

What I'm looking to add to this script is error logging. The commands run one after another, and I want to create an error log if one or more commands failed.
I guess that I need to use the ERRORLEVEL command, but I have no idea how to use and implement it to achieve my goal.

I would appreciate any input.
Thank you and advance for your time and attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could redirect stderr to find any errors that the commands spat out when executing

```
@echo off
echo Backing up to Skydrive
net use Z: \\https://d.docs.live.net/XXXX Password /user:Username 2>>log.txt
copy D:\Home\Data\file1.ext Z:\ 2>>log.txt
copy D:\Home\Data\file2.ext Z:\Documents 2>>log.txt
net use Z: /delete 2>>log.txt
for %%a in (log.txt) do if not %%~za gtr 0 del %%a /f /q
```

Obviously you only output on the ones that can actually give an error :)

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to create the log file only if an error occurs, or does it must be created anyway (even when blank)?

Comment: No worries, good question. I have added an extra line on the end to check if the file is empty in case there are no errors, if there aren't then it will be deleted.

Comment: Your welcome :) If this answered your question you should check the tick next to this to show it as accepted.